# htaccess redirection rule

Tags: .htaccess

I want to redirect

http://subdom.domain.com/guidelines/article1

http://subdom.domain.com/guidelines/article2

http://subdom.domain.com/guidelines/article3

to

http://subdom.domain.com/notsoguideline/noarticlepage/blahblah

so I wrote the following rule in .htaccess of my wordpress site but it doesn't seem to work

RewriteRule ^guidelines/([^/]+)/ /notsoguideline/noarticlepage/blahblah/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Check that your hosting supports and allows the use of .htaccess files.
- Ensure that you have `RewriteEngine On` in your .htaccess (before your custom rules)

If you create a nonsense .htaccess file what happens?  If nothing then your .htaccess file is not in use.